# Exception line 1:143 mismatched input '/' expecting StringLiteral near 'location' in table location specification

Tags: mysql, sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am Creating an external table for storing query results.
Below is the Query and Errror message.

```
hive> create external table result_teamquery1(teamname string,count int) row
 format delimited fields terminated by '\t' stored as textfile location
 '/home/biadmin/location/result_teamquery1’;

MismatchedTokenException(15!=286)
    at org.antlr.runtime.BaseRecognizer.recoverFromMismatchedToken(BaseRecognizer.java:617)
FAILED: ParseException line 1:143 mismatched input '/' expecting StringLiteral near 'location' in table location specification
```

I try many of the existing solution like "[MismatchedTokenException on hive create table query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25684823/mismatchedtokenexception-on-hive-create-table-query)".But it didn't work.PLs guide.

Comment: Is the `’` in `teamquery1’;` really in your actual code? That's a typographic quote, not a proper "programming" quote.

Comment: I fixed the error,I was executing the command from wrong directory path.